# In SDWebImageSwiftUI, which has more priority: the header Cache-Control or SDImageCache.shared.config.maxDiskAge?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage, sdwebimageswiftui

I am assuming that SDWebImageSwiftUI takes the header `Cache-Control max-age` into account when defining the cache expiration date (not sure though).

But what happens if I set `SDImageCache.shared.config.maxDiskAge` in the `AppDelegate`? Like this:

```
// Set the image cache expiration to one day.
SDImageCache.shared.config.maxDiskAge = 60 * 60 * 24
// 250 MB
SDImageCache.shared.config.maxDiskSize = 250 * 1024 * 1024
```

I want to be sure which cache rule will apply, this one or the header max-age.

Comment: I think you might want to look for `removeExpiredData` method that clean (by default when app enters background (see `shouldRemoveExpiredDataWhenEnterBackground`) https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/Core/SDDiskCache.m#L143

Comment: My question is not about the moment it is cleaned. It is about the priority of the request header over the global configuration.

Comment: By seeing how the cache is cleaned, it might help to understand what make the cache value outdated or not. I don't see the Cache-Control max-age in the code though.